# Is it possible to autogenerate an API with Microsoft Azure?

Tags: api, azure

I would like to host a Database and an API-Backend within Azure. But I want to do that without implementing code because I just want to run typical read/write actions.

Is it possible to generate an API for an existent Azure SQL Database? All "Creating API"-Examples I find in the Azure Documentation use ASP.Net or NodeJS. So is autogeneration possible with Azure?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no functionality to automatically provide an API interface over Sql Azure. The REST api that Azure provides is to manage the database, not to access that data.

You can use an Azure web-app to host your WebAPI auto-generated code. In Visual Studio, you can use Entity Framework database first approach to generate the API trivially. You will need to compile and publish it to a web app to get your API going.

You can find a pretty exhaustive tutorial at 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-rest-service-aspnet-api-sql-database/

(skip the MVC section altogether and just use WebAPI and EF)

Comment: OK, thanks, but I prefare using a Java backend. So is there an article which describes how to do the same using Java?

Comment: Don't think Microsoft has tool for java. You can take a look at http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/ 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378907/how-to-generate-spring-webmvc-crud-api