# Spring : Auto Generate CRUD Rest Controller

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Is there a way to generate spring rest crontroller for a business flow.

I want to generate CRUD services for given database object.
For example, "employee_mst" , generate CRUD services code automatically.
This is similar to what we used to have in hibernate or what we have in [loopback.io](https://loopback.io/) for node.
 Appreciate any help around it.

Comment: try it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378907/how-to-generate-spring-webmvc-crud-api

Answer (score 6):

I found a link that may answer your question: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/.

This text explains that Spring Data REST generates REST interfaces from Spring Data repositories.

I intend to try this but did not do so yet.

EDIT: I saw in my example application that Spring Data REST did what I expected. I could request all entities in my Spring Data repository using a HTTP request. The returned JSON contained also discovery information. You may prefer writing your own controller to have more control on what information is returned.